# Limit point and accumulation point of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers and $l\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.
Let $A=\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
I want confront this definitions:

1. $l$ is said to be a **limit value** of $(a_n)_n$ if there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that $\lim\limits_{k→∞}a_{n_k}=l$.
2. $l$ is said to be a **accumulation point** of $A$ if forall neighbourhood $I$ of $l$ we have $(I\setminus\{l\})\cap A\neq\emptyset.$
3. $l$ is said to be a **limit point** of $A$ if $\exists (x_n)_n$ sequence of elements of $A$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n=l$.

I observe that:

$1)\rightarrow 3)$ is obvious.

$1)\rightarrow 2)$ is false. For example if $a_n=1$ $\forall n$, then 1 is limit valor but no accumulation point.

$2)\rightarrow 3)$ is obvious.

$2)\rightarrow 1)$ is true with opportune use of axiom of choice.

$3)\rightarrow 2)$ is false. For example if $a_n=1$ $\forall n$, then 1 is limit point but no accumulation point.

My principal quest is if $3)\rightarrow 1)$ is true or not.
The problem is that a sequence of $A$ is not a subsequence of $a_n$ generally.

I think that is false and i ask a counterexample, please.

Comment: limit valor? I think u has typo and what is I?

Comment: When I learned I understood accumulation point = limitpoint. I I guessyou need to expand out the definition

Comment: if $1\Rightarrow 2 $ is false, and $1\Rightarrow 3$ is true, then $3\Rightarrow 2$ must be false...

Comment: Your counterexample $a_n=1$ proves that $3)\to 2)$ is false. You wrote it yourself in the $3)\to 1)$ part: "then $1$ is limit point but no accumulation point."

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{1-\frac  1 n, n \geq 1\} \cup \{2\}$. Take $l=2$. Then 3) holds but 2) does not (since $(1.5,2.5)$ does not contain any point of $A$ other than $2$.

[3) holds because the constant sequence $\{2,2,...\}$ converges to $2$].