# Question about accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I found the equivalent conditions for the accumulation point quite confusing.

By definition, $a$ is an accumulation point of a set $A \Longleftrightarrow$ there exists a sequence $a_n$ of $A$, such that **all elements of $a_n$ is different from each other** and ${\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}} a_n=a$.

> My first question is do all elements of $a_n$ different from each other mean $a_n$ is not a constant sequence(i.e. $a_n \equiv a$)? so $a$ is not an isolated point?

I can draw some equivalent conditions for the accumulation point.

1. $\forall \epsilon>0, B(a,\epsilon) \bigcap A \neq \emptyset$
2. $\forall \epsilon>0, B(a,\epsilon) \bigcap A$ has infinite elements.

$x \in B(a,\epsilon)$ means $|x-a| < \epsilon$

> My second question is '1' can be easily shown equivalent to there exists a sequence $a_n$ of $A$, such that  ${\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}} a_n=a$. So, **' all element of $a_n$ is different from each other**' seems redundant?

> My last question is '2' seems stronger than '1'? Can we show '2' from '1'?

[Limit point and accumulation point of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499082/limit-point-and-accumulation-point-of-a-sequence?rq=1) can answer several of my questions

Comment: I agree it's confusing. Unfortunately there exist two different concepts: An accumulation point **of a sequence** and an accumulation point **of a set**.

Comment: The way you worded $1.$ would make any $a \in A$ an accumulation point. This is because $a \in B(a,\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: You can fix $1$ by saying "$[B(a,\epsilon) \setminus \{ a \}] \cap A \neq \phi.$"